# Can't access server remotely

Tags: apache2

I've been running an Ubuntu Server for the past month to run my website. It's all be working fine, I had a few directory's for the different sites I was running and domains were pointed to them just fine. I then tried to start using Clean URLS (SEO Friendly URLS) so I made it that .htaccess could be used.

The issue was is that it didn't seem to be working so I thought I'd restart apache again and it still didn't seem to be working so I changed some of the config file and that made some errors and then I fixed them by restoring default but since then I can't access the server at all remotely.

This is from the browser to get onto the sites, on filezilla and also on puTTy. I checked I could still ping the server and I could and I re-booted it but still I can't access it.

Comment: It's possible that "I fixed them by restoring default" caused your current problem. What files did you change and then restore?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your config file is correct but it still isn't working with the default page you can try running these two commands,

`sudo service apache2 reload`

Which reloads the apache config file, then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This command restarts the apache server. At the very least one of them should give you an error message to pinpoint the problem more accurately.

Which should fix the problem. Assuming it is with apache. Are you sure the ssh port (port 22) is open on the server iptables?